# Como fazer um group by o Select é feito a mais de uma tabela

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  
    tblOrgao.eleicao_id as IdEleicao,
    tblCargo.orgao_id as IdOrgao,
    tblOrgao.orgao as Orgao,
    tblCargo.id as IdCargo, 
    tblCargo.cargo as Cargo, 
    tblLista.lista as NomeLista,
    tblListaCandidatos.candidato_id as NumberMembro 
FROM
tblOrgao  inner join 
    tblCargo on  tblCargo.orgao_id = tblOrgao.id, 
tblListaCandidatos LEFT JOIN 
    tblLista ON tblLista.id = tblListaCandidatos.lista_id
WHERE tblOrgao.eleicao_id = '20' AND tblLista.lista = 'A'
```

OutPut 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O numero de membro está a aparecer 3 vezes repetido 
Já tentei usar um `Group by tblCargo.id`

Tentei assim

```
SELECT  
    tblOrgao.eleicao_id as IdEleicao,
    tblCargo.orgao_id as IdOrgao,
    tblOrgao.orgao as Orgao,
    tblCargo.id as IdCargo, 
    tblCargo.cargo as Cargo, 
    tblLista.lista as NomeLista,
    tblListaCandidatos.candidato_id as NumberMembro 
FROM
tblOrgao  inner join 
    tblCargo on  tblCargo.orgao_id = tblOrgao.id, 
tblListaCandidatos LEFT JOIN 
    tblLista ON tblLista.id = tblListaCandidatos.lista_id
WHERE tblOrgao.eleicao_id = '20' AND tblLista.lista = 'A'
Group by tblCargo.id;
```

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Column 'tblOrgao.eleicao_id' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

O que pertendo obter é o seguinte **output**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Após essa recomendação ficou assim [Output](https://i.snipboard.io/F7EBcz.jpg )  e de qualquer uma das formas eu preciso mesmo que os dados de tblListaCandidatos.candidato_id as NumberMembro  apareçam nesta consulta

Comment: Poderias postar como estas fazendo o group by. nesse select ai não há group by algum

Comment: tbllistacandidatos possui campo de id do orgão?

Comment: não, tem o id do cargo

Comment: No lugar de apenas apresentar o comando SQL explique o que deseja obter.

Comment: Sem saber a estrutura das tabelas fica complicado. Se tiver como postar ficaria mais claro.

Comment: Note que, por exemplo para NumberMembro=1001, existe mais de valor para o campo orgao. Por qual motivo deve-se escolher um determinado valor em detrimento de outro? Dado que você não está utilizando nenhuma função de agregação talvez o uso da opção GROUP BY não seja a mais indicada para seu problema.

Comment: O que deveria eu usar para obter os valores dessa forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está fazendo um CROSS JOIN meio aleatório veja qual o resultado do comando abaixo e, se for o caso, o que precisa melhorar:

```
SELECT  
    tblOrgao.eleicao_id as IdEleicao,
    tblCargo.orgao_id as IdOrgao,
    tblOrgao.orgao as Orgao,
    tblCargo.id as IdCargo, 
    tblCargo.cargo as Cargo, 
    tblLista.lista as NomeLista,
    tblListaCandidatos.candidato_id as NumberMembro 
FROM tblOrgao INNER JOIN tblCargo ON (tblCargo.orgao_id = tblOrgao.id)
                INNER JOIN tblListaCandidatos ON (tblCargo.id = tblListaCandidatos.cargo_id)
                INNER JOIN tblLista ON (tblListaCandidatos.lista_id = tblLista.id)
WHERE tblOrgao.eleicao_id = '20' AND tblLista.lista = 'A';
```

Comment: Quais são as chaves estrangeiras de todas as tabelas envolvidas?

Answer (score 1):

Todos os campos do SELECT que são de agrupamento (campos que não são os calculados como SUM, COUNT e etc) devem estar na clausula GROUP BY

Se o que você precisa é ver apenas o resultado sem repetição você pode usar um DISTINCT ao invés de um GROUP BY para ficar mais limpo.

```
-- Com DISTINCT:
SELECT  DISTINCT
    tblOrgao.eleicao_id as IdEleicao,
    tblCargo.orgao_id as IdOrgao,
    tblOrgao.orgao as Orgao,
    tblCargo.id as IdCargo, 
    tblCargo.cargo as Cargo, 
    tblLista.lista as NomeLista,
    tblListaCandidatos.candidato_id as NumberMembro 
FROM tblOrgao 
inner join 
    tblCargo on  tblCargo.orgao_id = tblOrgao.id, 
tblListaCandidatos LEFT JOIN 
    tblLista ON tblLista.id = tblListaCandidatos.lista_id
WHERE tblOrgao.eleicao_id = '20' AND tblLista.lista = 'A'

-- Com GROUP BY:
SELECT tblOrgao.eleicao_id as IdEleicao,
    tblCargo.orgao_id as IdOrgao,
    tblOrgao.orgao as Orgao,
    tblCargo.id as IdCargo, 
    tblCargo.cargo as Cargo, 
    tblLista.lista as NomeLista,
    tblListaCandidatos.candidato_id as NumberMembro
FROM tblOrgao 
inner join 
    tblCargo on  tblCargo.orgao_id = tblOrgao.id, 
tblListaCandidatos LEFT JOIN 
    tblLista ON tblLista.id = tblListaCandidatos.lista_id
WHERE tblOrgao.eleicao_id = '20' AND tblLista.lista = 'A'
--É só remover os apelidos de coluna
GROUP BY tblOrgao.eleicao_id, tblCargo.orgao_id, tblOrgao.orgao,tblCargo.id, tblCargo.cargo, tblLista.lista,tblListaCandidatos.candidato_id
```